# Folded Cascode Gain

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, cascode

I am designing a single stage folded cascode amplifier.
My supply voltage is Vdd=1.2 and tail current= 40uA.
I am using gpdk 45nm technology. But in design I have used 200nm as the minimum length.
I am getting gain as 42dB. But my target is to get more than 70dB gain. 
Can I get 70dB gain with Vdd=1.2 and Itail=40uA ?

What is the maximum gain I can expect in 45nm technology with single stage folded cascode amplifier?

Comment: 70dB may be a stretch. Increasing the length may help. Maximum DC gain is in subthreshold. You can plot gm/Id while you vary the width to figure out how close you are. To get the best DC gain you want a near optimal current density [A/um]. Gm*Ro gives maximum gain for 1 transistor. Make sure your current source at the output of that transistor has at least the same or higher Ro. Make sure that Vds doesnt get to small in either the common source or common gate transistors.

Comment: Why didn't you include a schematic? Yes even if it is "obvious" you must include it. Also **think** what determines the gain. Draw a small signal equivalent circuit. Why are you expecting 70 dB gain from your design?